# Are the Boost preprocessor macros going to be ported to the standard library?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I'm often using the `BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE()` macro in order to transform a literal or constant number to a string. For example, my projects have a version number which I like to convert to a string to print in my usage (`--help`).

For example, it could look like this:

```
char const * notice = "%p version " BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(MAJOR_VERSION)
                      "." BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(MINOR_VERSION);
```

Are these Boost macros going to be moved to the standard library in the foreseeable future?

Answer (score 1):

This question is not a good fit for the site, but the answer, I think, is no: they're not going to be standardized. C++ is not big on using macros (they're more of a C thing, since C historically lacked generics and they're inherently non-type-safe, or even lexically safe).

The reason it exists in Boost, ironically, is mostly to allow libraries to be back-ported to old versions of C++ where the required language feature doesn't exist, or to get some kind of reflection-like behaviour (for which there is still no language support).

Comment: I thought some reflection was being introduced in C++20... or is it C++22? I suppose I could also try to use constexpr instead, but I don't think that would help string concatenation at compile time...